# How to handle SSL encrypted alert in Netty

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I've created server (10.32.240.50) with SslHandler. Client (10.32.240.5) connects to server and everything works fine. After some time client disconects with no reason. I've took tcp dump and saw there ncrypted alert right before disconect:
[image: wireshark]

[image: wireshark2]

I have no idea what client send me in this alert - it's encrypted. What could be the cause of this alert and why it leads to disconect? Is there any way to trace this events with netty?

Comment: If you set sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` it will trace _all_ JSSE (SSL/TLS) operations, which includes the received alert.

Comment: On a second read it is not clear anymore to me now who sends the alert to who. Is `.5` the client or the server? It is the first party to send an alert, then the other party sends an alert too, which is normal.

Comment: well then `javax.net.debug` includes both sent and received alerts. But if it's the application level (netty) deciding to close, JSSE doesn't say why -- and in general doesn't know, although you could set a breakpoint and look at the callstack which might help.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention that .5 is a client. .50 is a server

Comment: Client send alert, server responded with alert. After that server sends `FIN`. But this `FIN` seems more like result of this alert.

Comment: Ok, I slightly updated the end of my answer now that it is clearer that the client sends the first alert.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage it is difficult to see if your question is really related to programming, and hence ontopic here or not.

A TLS 1.2 alert can be many things, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2 which gives you the whole list:

> ```
>   enum { warning(1), fatal(2), (255) } AlertLevel;
>
>   enum {
>       close_notify(0),
>       unexpected_message(10),
>       bad_record_mac(20),
>       decryption_failed_RESERVED(21),
>       record_overflow(22),
>       decompression_failure(30),
>       handshake_failure(40),
>       no_certificate_RESERVED(41),
>       bad_certificate(42),
>       unsupported_certificate(43),
>       certificate_revoked(44),
>       certificate_expired(45),
>       certificate_unknown(46),
>       illegal_parameter(47),
>       unknown_ca(48),
>       access_denied(49),
>       decode_error(50),
>       decrypt_error(51),
>       export_restriction_RESERVED(60),
>       protocol_version(70),
>       insufficient_security(71),
>       internal_error(80),
>       user_canceled(90),
>       no_renegotiation(100),
>       unsupported_extension(110),
>       (255)
>   } AlertDescription;
>
>   struct {
>       AlertLevel level;
>       AlertDescription description;
>   } Alert;
> ```

Of course it is encrypted so if you really wanted to see it, you need to:

1. change the client so that it outputs the master secret and client random when doing the connection that triggers this error
2. record the relevant connection with wireshark
3. and then you will be able, inside wireshark, with the items in first point, to decrypt it (you can find numerous tutorials on how to do that)

From experience, if the alert happens after some application data the most probable case is "close_notify".  It is a "normal" case it just means that the server decides to shutdown the TLS socket (but not necessarily the TCP one) and hence warns (alerts) the other party about it.

If it is this case, then it is expected for the other party to send the same alert, and then the connection is shut down at the TCP level with `FIN`. So the chain of observations you have is expected. The only reason remaining is about the initial alert.

After clarification, since the first alert comes from `.5` which is the client, and not the server, it means the client that you do not control has decided to shutdown the TLS stream, for reasons only known by it
(if we still guess correctly that the alert is "close_notify" which is still only a guess that can be tested only if you decrypt the exchange per the instructions above, or maybe increase server verbosity, like this idea given by @dave_thompson_085 in comment: "If you set sysprop javax.net.debug=ssl it will trace all JSSE (SSL/TLS) operations, which includes the received alert. ")

Other than that, except asking the client operator/developer I see no way to understand why the client decided not to talk to you anymore. It also depends on the underlying application data exchanged, maybe it was indeed the end of the transmission and the client does not need the TLS stream anymore?

Comment: Sadly, I have no control over the client. I just see disconect on server side, and I have to guess what's going on. Maybe its "close_notify" and everyting is fine, but I want to be sure about it. Another problem is I have no idea how to reproduce this alert.

Comment: Try using another client (starting with `openssl s_client`) and see if you can reproduce the alert. If you control the server, you may have more luck changing it to give more data as it is generating this TLS alert, so it should have a reason, but that may be hidden far deeply in the TLS library you use, or even maybe some load balancer in front of it if TLS is terminated there.

Comment: `s_client` reaching end of input (if interactive usually ^D on Unix or ^Z on Windows) or being given the command uppercase-Q (on a line by itself) will send close_notify followed by 'physical' close (TCP FIN). There is no easy way to get it to send any other alert once the handshake is done.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 the alert is sent by the server. `openssl s_client` is just to try reproducing when the server sends this alert, and it all depends on what kind of traffic is exchanged inside the TLS stream. Hum not sure anymore from the OP where does the alert comes from now...